# Laravel Model Group By Default

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent, model, lumen

I have a Laravel application using eloquent which is returning offers with prices and other information as expected. What I would like to know is is there a way to apply a GroupBy in every instance a model is called.

In this case I have prices:

```
{
    [
        {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 345.30, 'personal': 1, 'business': 0},
        {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 432.40, 'personal': 0, 'business': 1},
        {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 464.50, 'personal': 1, 'business': 0},
        {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 634.20, 'personal': 0, 'business': 1}
    ]
}
```

Which I would like to display like:

```
{
    "personal":
        [
            {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 345.30, 'personal': 1, 'business': 0},
            {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 464.50, 'personal': 1, 'business': 0},
        ],
    "business":
        [
            {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 432.40, 'personal': 0, 'business': 1},
            {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 634.20, 'personal': 0, 'business': 1}
        ]
}
```

But this would apply in all instances the model is called. So at the moment calling an offer with the relationship to prices (Offer::with('prices')) gets:

```
{
    "offer":
        {
            "name": 'test',
            "description": 'tester',
            "prices":
            [
                {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 345.30, 'personal': 1, 'business': 0},
                {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 432.40, 'personal': 0, 'business': 1},
                {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 464.50, 'personal': 1, 'business': 0},
                {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 634.20, 'personal': 0, 'business': 1}
           ]
        }
}
```

But would like to get:

```
{
    "offer":
        {
            "name": 'test',
            "description": 'tester',
            "prices":
            [
                {
                    "personal":
                    [
                        {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 345.30, 'personal': 1, 'business': 0},
                        {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 464.50, 'personal': 1, 'business': 0},
                    ],
                    "business":
                    [
                        {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 432.40, 'personal': 0, 'business': 1},
                        {'offer_id': 1, 'price': 634.20, 'personal': 0, 'business': 1}
                    ]
               }
           ]
        }
}
```

There are a number of other complex relationships where this model is called, so unfortunately its not just a case of creating a group by in the controller when the model is used, it really needs to be the default mode of operation for the model. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
$myCollection='yousearch';
$personal= $myCollection->where('personal',1)->all();
$business= $myCollection->where('busines',1)->all();
$myNewCollection=array('personal'=$personal, 'business'=$business);
```

I am sure it can be improved, in any case you can apply some methods to work with collections: Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections